# "It makes (economic) sense", what are other adjective that can be used similarly?

Tags: word-request, adjectives

I am used to hearing sentences like:

> -It doesn't make **much** sense.
> -It makes **little** sense.
> -It makes
> **no** sense.
> -It makes **perfect** sense.

However, I find *it makes economic sense* really interesting since it expresses a concept rather than merely emphasizes *sense*.

I used [this](https://inspirassion.com/en/adj/sense) collocation dictionary to find the adjectives that are usually used with the noun *sense* and I found four that express concepts: legal, artistic, historical, and moral.

Then, I came up with the following sentences:

> 1. Saying that the world was one big country makes geographical sense.
>    *(referring to the theory of [continental drift](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continental_drift))
>    [image]*

> 2. Peafowls' colorful tail makes no evolutionary sense.
>    (*referring to the
>    theory which says that organisms developped ways to camouflage, not ways to
>    be more visible for predators)*
> 3. I think buying this 6 million dollar painting might make artistic
>    sense.
> 4. Hiring nine attorneys to work on this case makes legal sense.

I have two questions:

1. Do my sentences seem OK?
2. What are other adjectives that can be used similarly in the construction *it makes (adj) sense* to express concepts?

Comment: I admire your process but we are not here to correct sentences. That said, you are doing great on your own here. :)

Comment: Compiling a list of words is outside the scope of this site. Any adjective that could describe a reason for doing something or choosing one thing over another would probably work with “sense”. *The house’s curved walls made aesthetic sense, but were impractical when it came to furnishing the rooms.* *Talking to the cops without waiting for a lawyer was a bad idea in the legal sense, but it was the most expedient choice.*

Answer (score 1):

All your examples make grammatical sense.

What you have discovered is the malleability of English. Just about any adjective can be used to describe the adjectival sense of some action or idea.

Answer (score 1):

None of this makes sense. And all of it makes sense.

Geographical sense? We all live in this physical world. Land, oceans, planets, space, etc. It all makes sense.

Evolutionary sense? Evolution makes sense to most people I think. If not, those people don't make sense.

Artistic sense? In the eye of the beholder, but it makes sense to them.

Legal sense? Not sure